# landscape mode images in a full screen UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, landscape

Is it possible to let the UIImageView handle landscape images differently from portrait images?

I'll try to explain, I have `ImageViewController` with a `UIImageView` that fill the entire screen.
In some point the user launch a `UIImagePickerController` and choose a picture from the camera roll.
Then I create an instance of the `ImageViewController` with that picture and push it

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


    ImageViewController *ivc = [[ImageViewController alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [picker pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
    [ivc release];
}
```

The problem is, if the image is in landscape mode, it still fill the entire screen.
I want it to look like how the iPhone photos app present a landscape image (in the center of the screen with a black background).

Is there a build in way to show landscape mode images in UIImageView? or do I need to set the imageView frame according to the image orientation?

Answer (score 3):

Just set this:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeAspectFit;
```

And it will keep the proportion **and** fit the screen, not filling it.

Comment: This works great for landscape images, but when I set a portrait image it doesn't fill the entire screen, I get a small space in the right and left edges, why is that?

Comment: Grab the image size in viewDidLoad, see if the height is bigger then width. If it is, it's portrait image and you should set the AspectFill contentMode, if it isn't then it's either landscape or square and you should use AspectFit or Center contentModes.

Comment: This is because the ratio of the image in landscape is not the same ratio of the UIImageView. You can perform some calculation to check  the ratio of the image size, and according to it, define the contentMode to UIViewContentModeAspectFit or UIViewContentModeAspectFill

Comment: can u please give me an example how to do that?

Comment: `if (imageView.image.size.height > imageView.image.size.width) { imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeAspectFill;}
else { imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeAspectFit; }`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to change the `UIImageView`'s `contentMode` property according to the ratio of the picture.

So in `viewDidLoad` :

```
if (imageView.image.size.height > imageView.image.size.width) { 
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeAspectFill;
} else { 
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeAspectFit; 
}
```

and change that mode when the user switches to landscape, so for instance in the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` :

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toIntefaceOrientation)){
   if (imageView.image.size.height > imageView.image.size.width) { 
       imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeAspectFit;
   } else { 
       imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeAspectFill; 
   }
} else {
   if (imageView.image.size.height > imageView.image.size.width) { 
       imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeAspectFill;
   } else { 
       imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeAspectFit; 
   }
}
```

NB : note tested, but might work

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *imgView;
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Comment: I don't want it to fill the entire screen

Comment: It will not fill the entire screen. It will aspect fit your screen centered without scaling content to be 100% of the provided UIImageView.